# Django Ckeditor File Upload - Error With Path?

Tags: python, django, heroku, ckeditor, content-management-system

I'm trying to use `ckeditor_uploader` and receiving the following error when attempting to upload an image from the admin dashboard.

```
img-5485.JPG:1 GET https://fixmybike-staging.herokuapp.com/media/uploads/2020/06/23/img-5485.JPG 404 (Not Found)
```

I have no issues uploading a file when I run the server locally, so I'm assuming this is related to how Heroku handles media paths and how I've configured it.

`base.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bikemech',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

I'm also already using `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',`

`urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from bikemech import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ckeditor', include("ckeditor_uploader.urls")),
    path('', include('bikemech.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I've attempted a variety of configurations in `base.py` from other stack overflow posts with no luck. Also, Heroku is succeeding at running `collectstatic` so I don't believe that's the issue.

Comment: try the `re_path` approach I've done below.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this approach can help you. Also check, heroku doens allow images be rendered for long in its free service.

settings.py

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'

#config for differnt type of WYSIWYG functionalities
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': None,
    },
 }
```

main urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...

    path('search/', ex...)),
    path('chekout/', ex...),
    re_path(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```